# Android Studio SharedPreferences Error in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to refresh a Fragment with Sharedpreferences since 2 days, but only Errors:

> [Android Studio call fragment method from other fragment or activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682624/android-studio-call-fragment-method-from-other-fragment-or-activity/)

Now, every time when the user change the the tab of the tablayout, he has to click on a Button to refresh manually. But no one want this!

I hope anybody can remove the "updatebutton" 3 and 4 in the tab and make the refresh automaticly.

**Update:**
Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used this: [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Now the App works fine.
Thanks to everyone!